# How to translate to Black Speech this sentence "Eye of the Sauron is always watching"?

Tags: translation, tolkien-black-speech

How to translate to Black Speech phrase "Eye of the Sauron is always watching"? or more simply: "Sauron is always watching", or even more simply "Sauron is watching".

and how to write it in tengwar.

As I try to translate words: eye - hont, Sauron - Shakhbûrz. always - ûkil. watch - hon- , gon-.

I used Black Speech online translator: http://www.blackspeech.ru/los/index.php?page=5

But I doubt how to make full sentence from it. And How to write it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not an expert in Black Speech, so I'm going to follow the information from the blackspeech.ru website.

The basic word order of Black Speech is *SVO* (subject-verb-object), as in English, so the subject is *Sauron*, the verb is *watch*, and there is no object. Adverbs (*always*) are to be placed after the words they modify, so we end up with

> Sauron watches/is watching always

as the basic starting point. *Sauron* is straight forward,as there are no cases. With *watch* I would actually choose the translation *tud-*, as it has the sense of *guard*, which seems more appropriate here; in the third person singular this would be *tudat*. The adverb suffix is *-arz*, which gives us *ûkilarz*. So our sentence would be

> Shakhbûrz tudat ûkilarz

With the Tengwar transcriber on the same site it would be rendered as

[image: Tengwar rendering]

---

UPDATE: In case you want to say "Eye of Sauron", that would be the possessive ("eye Sauron-of"):

> Hont Shakhbûrz-ob tudat ûkilarz

and

[image: The Eye of Sauron is always watching (in Tengwar)]

There are no articles, so it's either *The Eye of Sauron* or *Eye of Sauron* — there is no distinction in Black Speech.